# folder as subdomain on click

Tags: php, .htaccess

assume i have a domain called as "something.in"..also there are multiple folders in it(buy,tour,ect)..
on the index page there are various links present like buying,touring ect....

What is happening is that when i click on buying the url is navigating to something.in/buy(foldername)/some-buy

i want it to be like  buy.something.in

Yes there are many similar topics related that is already present in stackoverflow itself....
But I need to know what changes has to be made so this happens only on CLICKING THE LINK it should navigate as "foldername.something.in/some-buy".using .htaccess..

IN OTHER WAY IT CAN BE SIMPLY SAID AS PRETTY URL ON CLICK...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have some confusion between subdomains and pretty urls. I'm not saying that it can't be done, far from it, but I feel that you have this confusion nevertheless.

Comment: Look into url rewriting with .htaccess files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just put the proper urls in your shopping page to begin with?

Instead of

```
<a href="/buy/product?id=foo">
```

have

```
<a href="http://buy.example.com/product?id=foo">
```

Comment: Thanx Marc B,Thats a good idea having said that, will that be useful in  SEO OPTIMIZATION in the long run?

Comment: No idea. Personally I couldn't care less about SEO. I view it as "Spam Enhancement Opportunities"

Comment: Also Marc B, if it is a single page in a folder it can be worked...if there are multiple pages in a folder,how can we proceed dynamically???

Comment: You don't. if I hit a site that's redirecting to me to `spam.junk.garbage.buy.etc...etc...etc....example.com`, I'll just go elsewhere. Hostnames should not be abused the way you're trying to.

Answer (score 0):

In your root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(\w+)/(.*) http://$1.something.in/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ,HOW TO GET THIS ONLY BY CLICKING A LINK?