# subdomain and folder issues

Tags: php, .htaccess

with reference to question that I previously posted

[folder as subdomain on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018925/folder-as-subdomain-on-click) ,i got the desired result in url  but i am getting the error message that

> Oops! Google Chrome could not find buy.something.in/somepage.php.

..Here is the code that i have written in .htaccess

> > RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^buy.something.in [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://buy.something.in/$1 [R=301,L]

where buy is folder name

2:)Before this i used HIDE URL technique where i was able to successfully remove the .php extension....After inserting the above code .php extension is again being displayed[in URL],but i am getting error message[PAGE COULD NOT BE FOUND] which i have mentioned above..So

- What may be the issue with the above code?
- Why is my HIDE URL also not working in junction with the above code?

  Can any one  please help me  in resolving these issues?
- Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Have you bothered updating your DNS so that buy.something.in has a valid IP address mapping? You cannot just magically create hostnames in your HTML and expect browsers to know what their IP address is...

Comment: ,I have updated in cpanel and now it is working fine...thanks